# Basic jquery & PHP session.upload_progress.name

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get the file progress working with the new session.upload_progress.name functionality in PHP 5.4.

So far my code is this:

```
<?
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jimbo").submit(function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajx.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#feedback").html(data + Math.random(999));
                }
            });
            //$("#feedback").html("hello " + Math.random(999));
        },500);
        //return false;
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>


<h1><a href="test.php">Upload</a></h1>
<br/>
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='jimbo'>
   <input type="hidden" name="<?=ini_get('session.upload_progress.name'); ?>" value="myupload" />
   <input type="file" name="file1" />
   <input type="submit" id='submitme' />
</form>

<div id="feedback">Hello</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And then the ajx.php file:

```
<? session_start(); ?>
<pre>
<?
    echo "SESSIONVAR<br/>";
    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
</pre>
```

Now.  When I click the submit button (after selecting a file), The file starts uploading, but the setinterval doesnt start.  However, If I have the `return false;` in there, I get the setInterval results, but the file doesnt start uploading.  If I submit the file without returning false, and in a seperate window view the contents of ajx.php, I can see that the variable is working fine and updating.  So how do I get the #feedback div to update once the form has been clicked?

**note** *the session array **is** populated*, the problem here is with the **jquery** and nothing else.

Comment: Have you thought about using javascripts' XmlHTTPRequest' object for this?

Comment: @ReinderWit yep, he use and Ajax request: `$.ajax`

Comment: For interesting, i had tested it on my root. For me, the progress is not available on all uploads. On 200 MB files, the progress will not shown. Is the file ~5-10 MB its work

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I actually meant using XmlHTTPRequest to handle the progression. It has an 'upload' property, which has a 'progress' event you can hook into...

Comment: @AdrianPreuss - I specifically stated that the session array is populated.

Comment: @ReinderWit, No i haven't can you provide source code?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve similar functionality using javascript XMLHttpRequest objects 'upload' property. It has a couple of events you can hook into, 'progress' is one of them.

here's a sample I've used. It will add a row with the progression (in %) to a `<div class="progression">` for each file from a `<input type="file">` field:

```
function startUpload() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("file1");

    $('.progression').show();
    for(var i = 0;i<fileInput.files.length;i++) {
        doFileUpload(fileInput.files[i]);
    }
}

function doFileUpload(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var data = new FormData();
    var $progress = $('<div class=\"progress\"><p>' + file.name + ':</p><span>0</span>%</div>');
    $('div.progression').append($progress);
    data.append("file", file);
    data.append("album", $("#album").val());

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        $progress.find('span').text(Math.ceil(percentComplete));
    };

    xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if(result.success == "true") {
             console.log("Great success!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Error! Upload failed");
        }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
        console.log("Error! Upload failed.");
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "/_admin/_inc/upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Comment: @AdrianPreuss **No**, it is not.  Please read my question properly before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @Chud37 have a look at Mozilla's dev pages: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest, there's a lot of interesting stuff you can use...

Comment: @ReinderWit, That is cool and thank you but I am so close to having this one work.  I just need to know what I am doing wrong in order to get it to run the `setInterval()` when the form is uploading.